# Select objects while using move, scale or rotate tool

Tags: interface, customization, keymap

I know it is possible to make this work. By default, when any of the transform tools is active you can not drag the cursor on an empty space of the scene to select the objects. But there is a way to fix it somewhere in preferences. I made this fix long time ago on my laptop, but now I can not find what exactly have I done to make it work Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, in the top bar, chose the action "Tweak" on Drag:

[image]

Comment: yep. That's it. Thanks!=)

Comment: @3DBear mark it as correct then